# How to parse json formatted text at the end of a txt file

Tags: python, json

I have a txt file that contains some plain text and a json styled text block. I want to parse the txt and extract the json block to a python dict object.

For example, the txt file may looks like:

```
1234567
asdfjkl
{
  "Name": {
    "given ": "kevin"
  },
  "info": [
    "asdf",
    "fda",
    "sdf"
  ]
}
```

and there's one and only one legit json block in each txt. Couldn't find anything in the `json` package. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Amm... what's desired output?

Comment: Can { or } occur outside the JSON? Is the JSON always at the end of the file?

Comment: 1. Find the line number of '{'
2. Use 'dom' in minidom and parse From that line number. This will do

Comment: @U9-Forward a dict object that contains everything from the json block

Comment: @PM2Ring 1. No 2. Yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, JSON always in the back:

```
from ast import literal_eval
with open('filename.txt','r') as f:
   s=f.read()
   print(literal_eval(s[s.index('{')-1:]))
```

Better using `json.loads`:

```
from json import loads
with open('filename.txt','r') as f:
   s=f.read()
   print(loads(s[s.index('{'):]))
```

Both output:

```
{'Name': {'given ': 'kevin'}, 'info': ['asdf', 'fda', 'sdf']}
```

Comment: Yeah I think the second one is better. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: `json.loads` is definitely better here than `literal_eval`, since it will correctly convert the JSON, so JS stuff like `null`, `true` & `false` get converted to the Python equivalents.

Comment: @PM2Ring Of course, it's much better that's why i said that, :-)

Comment: @PM2Ring Edited mine

Answer (score 0):

If you're in control of the input, don't do it this way. If the gal or guy on the input end is the client/boss, curse the code gods under your breath and write a helper function like this:

```
# returns a list of plaintext lines and a json string.
def split_text_and_json(filename):
    textlines = []
    jsonlines = []
    bracketcount = 0

    with open(filename) as f:
       for line in f.readlines():
           bracketcount += line.count('{')

           if bracketcount:
               jsonlines.append(line)
           else:
               textlines.append(line)
           bracketcount-=line.count('}')
    return (textlines, ''.join(jsonlines))

plaintextpart, jsonpart = split_text_and_json('file.txt')
```

You could do this inline if the JSON was always guaranteed to be the last part of the file.

Now for the bad stuff: You need to handle files that include the { } characters outside of the json. This script will throw errors in that case when you try to load the json.

Comment: Thanks! Actually the real use case is a bit complicated, while I just want to be lazy that don't want to find the original json file :D

Comment: This won't work if the JSON object contains unequal numbers of `{` and `}` string literals.

Comment: To emphasize, op should just reorganize the input if possible to be easily untangled.

Comment: Also I just realized that it won't work if the json is all on the same line.